# Importing a datetime field from csv/txt into Access

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access, datetime, import

I have the output of a SQL Server 2008 query saved to a text file and I am trying to link it to an Access database (Access 2007-2010).

The text file contains two date columns in the SQL Server 2008 `datetime` format, like this:

```
EFFECTIVE START DATE:
---------------------
2013-07-01 00:00:00.000 

EFFECTIVE END DATE:
-------------------
2014-06-30 00:00:00.000
```

In the Import wizard, I click Advanced and change the following:

- Code Page = Western European (Window) instead of Unicode (UTF-8)

For the 2 `datetime` columns:

- data type = Date/Time
- date order = YMT
- Date delimiter = -
- Leading zeros in dates = ticked

While still in the import wizard the data looks fine but as soon as the import is finished and I open the table in Access, I see *#Num!* in the two date columns.

I have tried a combination of settings in the import wizard (leave the code page as Unicode, not change the date order, not ticking the leading zeros in dates, etc) but in the end I had to import the dates as text, which stops me from doing any calculations now.

Many thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Is this being imported into a new table, or appended to an existing one?  And what is your reason for changing the Code Page value?

Comment: It is being imported into a new table rather than appended to an existing one. Even when I am not changing the code page and leaving it to the default Unicode (UTF-8) I still cannot successfully import the datetime columns so that should not be the issue. Thanks a lot, I really appreciate the help, it's my first question on stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just adding this as an answer, since it ended up being the one that worked:

If you have control over the output from SQL Server, you can change the format of the date field in your view/stored procedure. Something like

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [Field1], 101) AS Date1
```

That will strip the time off it, and Access should recognize it.

Answer (score 2):

> in the end I had to import the dates as text, which stops me from doing any calculations now.

True, you can't manipulate the text fields as true dates, but you can run a make-table query to convert them to real `Date/Time` values like so:

```sql
SELECT 
    ID, 
    CDate(Left([Field1],InStr([Field1],".")-1)) AS Date1, 
    CDate(Left([Field2],InStr([Field1],".")-1)) AS Date2 
INTO SqlDataWithRealDates
FROM SqlData;
```

The issue with the original import is that Access `Date/Time` values do not support fractional seconds so Access will never recognize the values as such if they include `00:00:00.000`. The above query removes the trailing `.000` before passing the strings to `CDate()`.

Another alternative as suggested by Johnny Bones in the comments below is to alter the SQL Server query to use something like `CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [Field1], 101) AS Date1` to remove the time component from the strings that will eventually be imported.

Comment: Thanks Gord. Are you saying that there is no other way and I have to 1st import it as a data type = text column and then re-convert it to date?

Comment: @user3249299 Practically speaking that's the only way to do it. Access `Date/Time` values do not support fractional seconds so Access will never recognize the values as such if they include `00:00:00.000`.

Comment: Well, if your layout never changes then it's probably not a big hassle to just have a macro run that uses your Import template, runs a Make Table that fixes those 2 columns as Gord says above, and then deletes the originally imported table.

Comment: **Or**, if you have control over the output from SQL Server, you can change the format of the date field in your view/stored procedure.  Something like SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [Field1], 101) AS Date1.  That will strip the time off it, and Access should recognize it.

Comment: I went back to the SQL query and did the convert as it is the simplest solution in my case. the CONVERT worked perfectly, thanks @Johnny Bones

Answer (score 0):

I found if you use "M/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss" as the date format (.NET), Access will import the date/time correctly, at least for if you are in the United States. Note, the hour is the 24 hour time. It won't work in 12 hour time with the AM/PM indicator. This is different than Excel, which does work with the 12 hour time. If you include milliseconds, it won't work. You can leave the time off if you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

If your output is CSV file, change the output format to "MM/DD/YYYY", and drop the time from the date.
It will import just fine.
If you need to use the time, make another column for it, and strip out the date leaving only the time. 
I was able to use hundreds of hours with two places.

Answer (score 0):

Access does import correctly the date and time information in the data. You need not drop (or remove) the time information. I have not tested for fractional seconds. However, if you have duplicates in the data column you may need to fix it and also you should correctly set the date format (YMD, DMY, etc.)
Here is a recent link to a correctly imported text file.
http://hodentekmsss.blogspot.com/2017/02/importing-text-file-into-ms-access.html

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same issue while importing CSV file with datetime. What I had done to solve this issue was by splitting date and time and merge.

```
Convert(varchar, yourdatecolum, 101 ) + ' ' + Convert(varchar, yourdatecolumn, 108)
```